# How to split DataFrame rows at Nth character in a column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, split, list-comprehension

I have encountered a scenario where in a column I have the possibility of 0,2,4, or 6 character strings that I need to expand into 1,2, or 3 rows, as follows:

Current

| Employee | Pay Grade |
| --- | --- |
| John | 7A5B |
| Kathy |  |
| Tom | 9A9B4C |

Desired

| Employee | Pay Grade |
| --- | --- |
| John | 7A |
| John | 5B |
| Kathy |  |
| Tom | 9A |
| Tom | 9B |
| Tom | 4C |

I have tried .split() and .explode() but having some trouble splitting each string into groups of 2 characters

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution with [`extractall`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extractall.html) :

```
N = 2 # N'th character

out = (
    df[["Employee"]].join(
        df["Pay Grade"].str.extractall(r"(.{%s})" % N)[0]
        .rename("Pay Grade").droplevel(1)
    )
)
```

Output :

```
print(out)

  Employee Pay Grade
0     John        7A
0     John        5B
1    Kathy       NaN
2      Tom        9A
2      Tom        9B
2      Tom        4C
```

Answer (score 0):

You're close. I think `split` is the tough part here. The itertools pairwise recipe would do nicely with `explode`:

```py
def pairs(x: str):
    it = iter(x)
    vals = []

    while True:
        a, b = next(it, ''), next(it, '')
        if not all((a, b)):
            break
        vals.append(''.join((a, b)))

    if a:
        vals.append(a)
    return vals


df['Pay Grade'].apply(pairs).explode()
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of splitting you should try [pandas.Series.str.slice](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.slice.html)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can separate the string using the apply method and split the values in new rows:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "Employee": ["Jhon", "Kathy", "Tom"],
        "Pay Grade": ["7A5B", np.nan, "9A9B4C"]
    }
)
df["Pay Grade"].fillna("", inplace=True)

df["Pay Grade"] = df["Pay Grade"].apply(
    lambda value: '|'.join([value[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(value), 2)])
)

df = df.join(
    df.pop("Pay Grade").str.extractall(r"([^|]+)").droplevel(1)[0].rename("Pay Grade")
).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution:

```py
import re


df = (
    df.assign(**{"Pay Grade": df["Pay Grade"].apply(lambda x: re.findall(r"..", x))})
    .explode("Pay Grade")
    .fillna("")
)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
  Employee Pay Grade
0     John        7A
0     John        5B
1    Kathy          
2      Tom        9A
2      Tom        9B
2      Tom        4C
```

---

OR: without `re`:

```py
df["Pay Grade"] = df["Pay Grade"].str.extractall(r"(..)").groupby(level=0).agg(list)
print(df.explode("Pay Grade").fillna(""))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `wrap` from `textwrap` to chop the `Pay Grade` data into 2 character chunks, explode those values and then `join` them back to your original df:

```py
import textwrap

out = (df
    .drop('Pay Grade', axis=1)
    .join(df['Pay Grade']
          .apply(textwrap.wrap, args=[2])
          .explode()
    )
    .fillna('')
    .reset_index(drop=True)
)
```

Output for your sample data:

```
  Employee  Pay Grade
0     John         7A
1     John         5B
2    Kathy
3      Tom         9A
4      Tom         9B
5      Tom         4C
```